# Free Web Hosting like Geocities?

Tags: web-hosting

Since [Geocities](http://geocities.yahoo.com/) is closing down soon, I'm looking for a suitable replacement.

This is for personal use, so bandwidth and diskspace isn't important. That's why I've been using Geocities' meager 15 MB space for YEARS. :)

Any good recommendations?

**UPDATE:** Oops, I reread the FAQ after it's closed, and it doesn't seems like I can post questions like this. On the other hand, I managed to get some noteworthy recommendations to start, so it's totally worth it. :)

Also, for those who ended up here, check the really useful 
"[Where can I ask questions that aren’t IT questions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1504/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-it-questions)".

Comment: Ah geocities - we hardly knew ya :-) I'm really gonna miss that site.

Answer (score 6):

Try [google sites](http://sites.google.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I used freehostia for a while, and it wasn't so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Google sites is nice, but you might also want to consider:

http://x10hosting.com/ has a good reputation as a free web hosting service.

https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/ isn't free, but it's stupidly cheap and the pennies a month it'll cost could well be worth it for the additional flexibility it offers over a completely free service.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a site at http://www.110mb.com/ for over a year  now.  The up-time is great and its totally free.

I think you have to FTP the site over.